# PS PDF Conversion text issues

Tags: pdf, text, printing, photoshop

having a bit of a weird issue that I can't for the life of me figure out how to solve. It may just be a blond moment on my part but I've been scratching my head with this one for a while.

Basically I've made a load of PS PDF files in CS6 and used Acrobat Pro DC to merge the files into one big file. Granted this may not be the most efficient way to work with PDFs but it seemed like the way that made the most sense to me. Anyway I've been doing this for a while and I've not really had any issues however when I did it today I hit a little snag. Several pages in the document come out with their text all mangled. The odd thing is that the text appears to look fine in the DC viewer but if I print them out or view them in Windows Reader they look deformed.

I've tried a load of different ways to try to solve the problem but I can't really find the answer I'm looking for. I've tried a number of different file formats and different printing settings (which I now realize are useless as it's messed up in Reader as well as in print). I've also tried rasterizing the text which seems to work but obviously the text becomes unselectable in the PDF views so I'd prefer to use this as a last resort and find the actual root of the problem.

I can only assume that it's an issue on photoshops side as the majority of the pages come out fine and they all use the same base template and same fonts.

Any insight into this will be really helpful.

Comment: Can you share a sample PDF illustrating the issue?

Comment: http://i29.photobucket.com/albums/c265/seph-53/pdfissue_zps0cxn9uzl.png

Comment: Please, what is a *"PS PDF file"*?

Comment: The photobucket link goes to a PNG (maybe depicting a page of a PDF), but not to a *"sample PDF illustrating the issue"...